# eonasdan bootstrap 3 datetimepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Need help with setting dates to datetimepicker calendar.

I am using this calendar to select the month, how do I set the month for the months from server side?

```
$(function() {
        $('.monthYear').datetimepicker({
            viewMode: 'months',
            format: 'MM/YYYY'
        });
    });
```

I tried:

```
$('.monthYear').datetimepicker.month = 0;
$('.monthYear').datetimepicker.year = 2013;
```

But when I click the calendar icon it's showing current month.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using v4 you can fill in the value in the textbox and it will set the picker to the correct date.

You can set the date via the [`date`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) function

```
$('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").date(1/2013);
```